# Flutter: keyboard automatically shows up

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm navigating to the next page within my Flutter app.

On the next page there are a few Forms where a user can enter text.

```
final _form2Key = GlobalKey<FormState>();
```

```
Padding(
  padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 8.0),
  child: Container(
    width: screenWidth / 1.1,
    height: screenHeight / 5.5,
    child: Form(
      key: _form2Key,
      autovalidate: true,
      child: TextFormField(
        autofocus: true,
        validator: (val) {
          if (val.trim().length < 3 || val.isEmpty) {
            return "Too short";
          } else if (val.trim().length > 200) {
            return "Too long";
          } else {
            return null;
          }
        },
      onSaved: (val) => description = val,
      decoration: InputDecoration(
        border: OutlineInputBorder(),
        filled: true,
        fillColor: Colors.white,
        labelText: "",
        labelStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: 15.0),
        hintText: " ",
      ),
    ),
  ),
),
```

Everything 'works', but after navigating  to this new page, the keyboard shows up automatically and is focussed on the textfield.

Is it possible to avoid the keyboard popping up and only show the keyboard when the user presses the form?

Thanks  in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

your keyboard is automatically popping up because you have set `autofocus` to `true`, please modify to `false` or remove that property to avoid keyboard from automatically popping up

```
final _form2Key = GlobalKey<FormState>();
```

```
Padding(
  padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 8.0),
  child: Container(
    width: screenWidth / 1.1,
    height: screenHeight / 5.5,
    child: Form(
      key: _form2Key,
      autovalidate: true,
      child: TextFormField(
        autofocus: false, // modified
        validator: (val) {
          if (val.trim().length < 3 || val.isEmpty) {
            return "Too short";
          } else if (val.trim().length > 200) {
            return "Too long";
          } else {
            return null;
          }
        },
        onSaved: (val) => description = val,
        decoration: InputDecoration(
          border: OutlineInputBorder(),
          filled: true,
          fillColor: Colors.white,
          labelText: "",
          labelStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: 15.0),
          hintText: " ",
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ),
),
```